# How would I implement a tournament like this? C++

Tags: c++

I have an array of 16 (example below). Each match of the tournament involves displaying two restaurants, prompts to choose his favorite one, and removing the losing restaurant from the tournament.
It is like a bracket system; i.e., a restaurant does not reappear in another match until all other restaurants have also appeared in a match for that round). So start with 8 matches, then 4, then 2.
Do not allow the tournament to begin unless the number of restaurants is equal to 16.
I am pretty new to C++. Anyone have a decent outline or suggestions/paths I should look at?

```
string restaurants[] = {"Texas Roadhouse,","On The Border,","Olive Garden,","Panda Express,","Cracker Barrel,","IHOP,","Panda Express,","Pei Wei"};
```

Comment: This seems like homework. Is it? As a first step, I suggest coming up with an algorithm, written in pseudo code to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just going to write the gist of the code, please explore further on how you would want to implement it.

```
    //assume arr is the array of 16 and length =16 initially
  while(length >0)
    {
    for(i=0;i<length; i=i+2)
     {
      int first= rand % (16-i);

      int second=rand % (16-i);
        while(first==second)
         second=rand%16;

      int chosen=choose_restaurant(arr,first,second,length);
      //return either first or second, depending on what is chosen

      if(chosen ==first)
        remove_restaurant(arr,second,length);
      else
        remove_restaurant(arr,first,length);

     }
   length=length/2;
  }

//the remove_restaurant function must move the removed restaurant from the array
//And move the selected restaurant to the end
```